# Return from deep closures

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have some code for example -

```
    loadImages(pos - 1,function(){
        loadImages(pos,function(){
            loadImages(pos + 1);    
        });
    });

function loadImages(key){   
    $('.slide:nth-child('+key+') .imgholder').each(function(){
        par = $(this).parent();
        imgHold = $(this);

        if (loaded_images.indexOf($(imgHold).data('img-src')) > 0){
            return true;
        } else {        
            $(imgHold).attr('src',$(imgHold).data('img-src')).on('load', function() {
                if (!$(imgHold).hasClass('fgimg')){                 
                    $(par).css('background-image','url('+$(imgHold).data('img-src')+')');                   
                } else {
                    $(imgHold).css('visibility','visible');
                }                   

                // How do I return loadImages from here??
            })      
        }
    })
}
```

I want to trigger code after this function has completed so I need to return true at my // comment line. What is the official/best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a callback:

```
function loadImages(key, callback){   
    $('.slide:nth-child('+key+') .imgholder').each(function(){
        par = $(this).parent();
        imgHold = $(this);

        if (loaded_images.indexOf($(imgHold).data('img-src')) > 0){
            return true;
        } else {        
            $(imgHold).attr('src',$(imgHold).data('img-src')).on('load', function() {
                if (!$(imgHold).hasClass('fgimg')){                 
                    $(par).css('background-image','url('+$(imgHold).data('img-src')+')');                   
                } else {
                    $(imgHold).css('visibility','visible');
                }                   
                callback(true);
                // How do I return loadImages from here??
            })      
        }
    })
}
```

Usage:

```
loadImages(key, function(yourVar){
    console.log(yourVar); // true
});
```

You have to pay attention on cases when callback is not invoked.

More info: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

Comment: I've updated my question because I need to run this function multiple times - even if the image can't be found or doesn't load. I like your answer but does this apply with the tweak (based on your answer)?